# JSF PrimeFaces nested variable

Tags: jsf, arraylist, primefaces, nested

Is it possible get variable from JSF to primefaces like below?

```
 <p:graphicImage library="images" name="#{home.hotelsImage['#{home.placeValue}']}"/>

#{home.hotelsImage['#{home.placeValue}']}
```

I'm trying get value of hotelImage[1] or hotelImage[2] with placeValue variable.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You cannot embed EL expressions. Instead, you might be able to do `#{home.hotelsImage[home.placeValue]}`

Comment: Anything written inside single quotes is read as String. The answer is #{home.hotelsImage[home.placeValue]} like @XtremeBiker said

Comment: no need of second `#` in EL